# How to pick pairs of columns, plot them against each other in a bar chart pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, data-analysis

I have imported the required libs:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psycopg2 as pg
```

I have a data frame as follows:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'non_read_avg': [0.58], 'non_write_avg': [0.75], 'non_mat_avg':[0.45], 'non_rwm_avg':[0.14],
          'rel_read_avg': [0.68], 'rel_write_avg': [0.70], 'rel_mat_avg':[0.75], 'rel_rwm_avg':[0.34]})
```

I want to select pairs of columns from this data frame and plot them against each other:

```
df.plot(x=['non_read_avg','rel_read_avg', 'non_write_avg','rel_write_avg'], kind='bar')
```

Then label the first pair ('non_read_avg','rel_read_avg') as 'Reading' (on the x axis), label the second pair ('non_write_avg','rel_write_avg') as 'Writing'. On the graph have two colors for each pair: one representing the 'religious' say blue, the other is 'non-religious' say green. I will need to do this for every column in the dataframe, basically having pairs of bars on the same graph and label them differently. Is this possible to do?

Comment: I'm not sure your question is very clear. Do you want a graph with just 2 points on it? What is "religious" and "non-religious"? How do you select the pairs? Do you want every possible pairs of values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a nice data wrangling problem. My suggestion would be to organise the data differently to start with.

```
df_rearanged = pd.DataFrame({
    'rel' : [0.68, 0.70, 0.75, 0.34],
    'non' : [0.58, 0.75, 0.45, 0.14]
    },index = ['read', 'write', 'mat', 'rwm']
)
```

In this way you have all the information you need on the rows and columns of the dataframe

[image]

And the plotting becomes dead easy & exactly what you want.

```
df_rearanged.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

[image]

I hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much CarlosLosLas. This is excatly what I wanted. Finally some people out there with the ability to understand what they are reading :)

Comment: Thank you man seriously. I have been on this question for my university assignment for days, and right now, at this very second IT IS SOLVED.